# Packet Forwarding / Proxy Server

Tags: router, proxy

Here's my setup:

1. An Internet router connected to my ISP
2. A Linux box connected to the router with one network card, and
   connected to a switch with the other.
3. A Windows box connected to the switch.

What I'm attempting to do is to code a Python script to basically allow the Windows 7 box to communicate with the Internet, as if the Linux box was not there; a transparent proxy if you like.

I have set the default gateway for the Windows box to be the Linux box, so anytime it attempts to access the Internet, the packets get routed to the Linux machine.

The Linux machine is listening on the internal network card.  It lifts the packet from a raw socket, then rewrites the dst MAC address to forward the packet to the router, and replaces the src IP address with the external facing network card.  This packet then gets send out from the external NIC.  The src MAC address is set to be the external NIC.

So, as far as the router is concerned, it is receiving this data from the Linux box.  So, the router routes it to the Internet and then sends the response back to the Linux box.

The external card is also listening to network traffic, and any incoming raw packets that has a matching MAC address, it lifts off the network, changes the dst MAC address to the Windows machine, the dst IP address to the Windows machine, and the src MAC address as the internal network interface.  It then sends it over the internal card.

As far as the Windows machine is concerned, it sent a packet to the Linux box (the default gateway), then received a response.

This is correctly working when I try to ping Internet servers (like `8.8.8.8`).  Looking at the output on the Linux box, I see the packet coming in on the internal card, then exiting on the external one with the modified header.

Then, shortly after, I see the response coming back from the external card, getting modified and then sent out over the internal card.

I have written classes to calculate IP checksums, etc., so this is not an issue.

Then I see the ping response being picked up by the Windows machine.

So with this setup, Ping is working fine.  I can ping `8.8.8.8`.  I have configured the Windows box to use DNS server `8.8.8.8`, which we know it can access.

Yet, when I try to browse the Internet, using IE or Firefox, I cannot.

I can see the DNS requests go through the internal network card, get modified, and then get sent out on the external card.  This time, however, instead of protocol 1 as for ping, it's protocol 17 which is UDP.

It doesn't matter how long I wait, however, the response never appears on the external card, as in nothing comes in from `8.8.8.8` back to the Linux box.

It does when using ping, but not when doing DNS lookup.

As I said, DNS has been manually configured to be `8.8.8.8` and `4.4.4.4`, and I see the DNS requests going out to the Internet router.

Nothing ever comes back.  Any ideas what might be the difference here, and what things I should be looking into as potential issues?

Please don't recommend I use some other software package as a solution to this problem, as I have looked into it and they do not suit my requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem will be that the transport layer protocols will need to be fixed, too. For example, TCP has a checksum that is predicated on the pseudo-header that includes the IP source and destination addresses. Your web browsing will need to use TCP, so you will need to fix the TCP headers. See [*RFC 793, Transmission Control Protocol*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793):

> Checksum:  16 bits
>
> The checksum field is the 16 bit one's complement of the one's
> complement sum of all 16 bit words in the header and text.  If a
> segment contains an odd number of header and text octets to be
> checksummed, the last octet is padded on the right with zeros to form
> a 16 bit word for checksum purposes.  The pad is not transmitted as
> part of the segment.  While computing the checksum, the checksum field
> itself is replaced with zeros.
>
> The checksum also covers a 96 bit pseudo header conceptually prefixed
> to the TCP header.  This pseudo header contains the Source Address,
> the Destination Address, the Protocol, and TCP length. This gives the
> TCP protection against misrouted segments.  This information is
> carried in the Internet Protocol and is transferred across the
> TCP/Network interface in the arguments or results of calls by the TCP
> on the IP.
>
> ```
>              +--------+--------+--------+--------+
>              |           Source Address          |
>              +--------+--------+--------+--------+
>              |         Destination Address       |
>              +--------+--------+--------+--------+
>              |  zero  |  PTCL  |    TCP Length   |
>              +--------+--------+--------+--------+
> ```
>
> The TCP Length is the TCP header length plus the data length in octets
> (this is not an explicitly transmitted quantity, but is computed), and
> it does not count the 12 octets of the pseudo header.

UDP can use a checksum, too. It is optional for UDP on IPv4, but mandatory on IPv6. If your UDP is using a checksum, then you must fix that. See [*RFC 768, User Datagram Protocol*](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc768.txt):

> Checksum is the 16-bit one's complement of the one's complement sum of
> a pseudo header of information from the IP header, the UDP header, and
> the data,  padded  with zero octets  at the end (if  necessary)  to
> make  a multiple of two octets.
>
> The pseudo  header  conceptually prefixed to the UDP header contains
> the source  address,  the destination  address,  the protocol,  and
> the  UDP length.   This information gives protection against misrouted
> datagrams. This checksum procedure is the same as is used in TCP.
>
> ```
>               0      7 8     15 16    23 24    31 
>              +--------+--------+--------+--------+
>              |          source address           |
>              +--------+--------+--------+--------+
>              |        destination address        |
>              +--------+--------+--------+--------+
>              |  zero  |protocol|   UDP length    |
>              +--------+--------+--------+--------+
> ```
>
> If the computed  checksum  is zero,  it is transmitted  as all ones
> (the equivalent  in one's complement  arithmetic).   An all zero
> transmitted checksum  value means that the transmitter  generated  no
> checksum  (for debugging or for higher level protocols that don't
> care).

Your application protocols, e.g. HTTP/HTTPS, may also need to be fixed. Also, if your web browsing is using SSL, then you can have other problems, too, that may be much more difficult to deal with since the TCP payload will be encrypted. Unfortunately, protocols above OSI layer-4 are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: If you want the Linux box to be a gateway and no other software as stayed here's a site with great explanation of set up. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-forward-ports-through-a-linux-gateway-with-iptables

Comment: Thanks, that's a really helpful explanation and explains what's going on

Answer (score 0):

If DNS doesn't work, nothing relying on it will. Obviously, you're having a problem with 'routing' UDP packets (you more or less implemented a stateless NAT router).

UDP uses a ["pseudo IPv4 header"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#IPv4_Pseudo_Header) for the purpose of calculating the checksum. If you don't recalculate it as well the packets will get dropped. As Ron's pointed out, TCP uses the same concept and requires checksum recalculation inside the segment.

Comment: OK, good to know what the name of the thing I'm trying to do is.